# add a range cloumn in spark sql or hive query

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a data where

```
 id amount
 1   200
 2   350
 3   450
 4    501
```

I want to add a column which defines the range of its values

```
id amount  Range
 1   200   100-200
 2   350   300-400
 3   450   400-500
 4   501   500-600
```

How can i achieve this in spark or hive .

Comment: create struct<int,int> for range input representation

Comment: base on what are the ranges ? I mean it'a kind of a segmentation with step 100 ?

Comment: yes but this has to be done dynamicaly

Comment: can you give example with struct<int,int>

Comment: The request is very unclear at this point. **(1)** What do you mean by "dynamically"? **(2)** what do you want to do with "struct<int,int>"? hold the range or the combination of id and amount?

Answer (score 0):

```
select  id
       ,amount

       ,concat_ws 
        (   
            '-'
           ,cast (floor ((amount-1)/100)*100 as string)
           ,cast (ceil  (amount/100)    *100 as string)
        )                                               as range

from    mytable
;
```

---

```
+----+--------+---------+
| id | amount |  range  |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 |    200 | 100-200 |
|  2 |    350 | 300-400 |
|  3 |    450 | 400-500 |
|  4 |    501 | 500-600 |
+----+--------+---------+
```